# Instruments (tools) used by a thief

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a good term for instruments (tools) a thief uses?

> Thief tools
>
> Thief stuff
>
> Thief gear

Or something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Tools" is the most appropriate term and I would use the following phrases:

> The thief's tools...
>
> The thieving tools...

If there is more than one thief:

> The thieves' tools...

Answer (score 4):

In America at least, the normal term is *burglary tools*.  Burglary is surreptitiously entering a building for purposes of theft, so burglary tools would include tools for picking locks, breaking doors, etc.

Comment: +1: I usually hear this as *burglar's tools* though. "Thief's tools" just sounds odd to me.

Comment: A variation is "tools of burglarious purpose" which sounds much more legalese while meaning the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

> The thief slipped through the open
>   window, pulled out *the tools of her
>   trade* from the knapsack, and walked
>   toward the safe.

Comment: She pulled out her *lock picks*